# Why my harddisk got unrecognized from last few week in BIOS?

Tags: hard-drive, motherboard

I have used my current hard-disk for 1-2 years. It worked fine until I changed my motherboard .

Sometime it does not recognize the hard disk. If I unplug the hard drive cables and plug them again it's work. I have tried twice and both times solved problem this way.

What could be causing this? Did allocating 1024 MB RAM to graphics cause this?

Comment: From your mention of more graphics ram, did you install a video card as well? I'm leaning towards the PSU somehow not having enough overall power to power the new system, but more information would be nice. What *else* is different between the new and old systems?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek nope, I don't put any graphic card. My means to reserve the 1024 Memory to Computer for Graphic.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have SATA loop fastener. Give it to an enemy).

## not use it!

[image: not use it!]

Take old simple SATA cable and all be work).

[image: good SATA able]

The shorter cable is better. If possible, do not pull on it. And the sharp bend.

Comment: What is the latch doing to cause it to not function properly?

Comment: @Luke The constructed latch properly. Poorly kept under vibration. Poor kept on hard drives in which the connector does not provide for the latch.

Comment: Almost all my drives have the newer type of cable and it works fine. I'd second luke and wonder why you think the cable with the fastener is the issue

Comment: @JourneymanGeek You are lucky and experience refute repair shops for data recovery.